# Angular2 - *ngIf and async observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have problem with using *ngIf with observable variables. The thing is that when I hide element with ***ngIf**, and show it again, values won't load so:

```
        <div *ngIf="showDiv">
             {{ someObservable$ | async }}
        </div>
```

Basically when showDiv is set to **true** at the first place, the someObservable loads, but when I set it to **false** and then again to **true** , value won't load. What's wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE:

Thanks to j2L4e, for his hint!

`BehaviorSubject` is the key!

See this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/whkrQk3tHCJCvvi6rlaE?p=info

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } 'rxjs/Rx';
//import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (click)="showMe = !showMe">Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <br />

      <div *ngIf="showMe">
        sbj1: {{  _subj1 | async  }}
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="showMe">
        obs1: {{  _obs1 | async  }}
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="showMe">
        obs2: {{  _obs2 | async  }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  private showMe = false;

  private _subj1 = new BehaviorSubject<string>();
  private _subj2 = new Subject<string>();
  private _obs1 = this._subj1.asObservable();
  private _obs2 = this._subj2.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

    this._subj1.next('in constructor');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._subj2.next('after view init..');
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` is what you'd need here. It caches a single value.